# Taking undergraduate course by a graduate student, officially?

Tags: graduate-school, coursework

I am supposed to start my graduate studies (M.A.Sc.) at a university in Ontario, Canada, soon. My potential research theme (as I've talked about it with my supervisor) does need to some background in `chaos dynamics` & `fractal geometry`... I've tracked the host university and could not find any related course, planned by either of the departments... So, I just tried to check the other universities, in the neighborhood, for finding any related course to be take it, as a guest student, based on the policies.

One fully-related course has been found, presented in the other university, named "Chaos & Fractals"... But it is an ***undergraduate course***...!

All this said, ***Does any body know whether I will be authorized to take an undergraduate course as a graduate student (to be counted among my required credits, of course) or not?!***

Thanks in advance

Comment: Taking a course at another university for credit can be bureacratically complicated. But informally auditing a class without receiving credit is likely quite easy.

Comment: @TomChurch: Just consider possible to take the course as guest student. Furthermore, as I've asserted within the question's body, I am eager to take the course as a part of the my roster of official courses, not just auditing that.

Comment: @Rori: You mean there is no hard-coded code of ethics to decide about this case by the universities?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No one can answer this question, except *possibly* your new supervisor. The bureaucratic issues involved in having a graduate student take an undergraduate course for credit, not to mention a course at **another university**, are very complicated and will be different at each institution.

(Before you spend any time trying to answer this question, you should check with your supervisor to make sure that they *want* you to take this course. For example, they might feel that despite the overlap in course material, taking this course would not be a good use of your time.)